# Python 2.7 Fatal error when loading application configuration:Unknown url handler type

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm experiencing the following error attemtpting to run helloworld application

```
Fatal error when loading application configuration:Unknown url handler type
```

`app.yaml` code follows :

```
application: helloworld 
version: 1 
runtime: python27
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /*
script: helloworld.py
```

Comment: does it work on localhost?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the error log? I am expecting there should be huge number of lines that would explain the error!

Comment: Please make sure the two missing space characters before `script: helloworld.py` are a transcription error. YAML, like Python, relies on correct indentation. Also, if you're using 2.7, you should be using WSGI, and therefore setting up an .app script and not a .py script. Also, I'm *almost sure* you did not mean to use that regular expression, and probably meant either `/` or `/.*`.

Answer (score 0):

same problem was

Ive fixed it by removing space before
"- url"
and check if you have two spaces befor "script"